# Is $f(x) = x^{5/3} − 5x^{2/3}$ defined over $(-\infty, 0]$?

Tags: calculus

I've encountered this question: Find and describe all local extrema of
$$f(x) = x^{5/3} − 5x^{2/3}.$$
Also indicate on which regions the function is increasing and decreasing.

I've managed to find the extrema, but I am not sure whether the function is defined on $(-\infty, 0]$. To make sure I looked on the internet at some graphing calculators and some of them graphed the function on that interval while others did not. Is it defined on that interval?

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: They probably mean that, for $y < 0$, $$y^{b/3} = (-1)^{b/3}(-y)^{b/3} = -\bigg((-y)^{b/3}\bigg)$$

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that $$x^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{x^2}.$$ This is an old story, since one usually defines $x \mapsto x^\alpha$ only for $x>0$. However, notation is never given once and for all, so that we should be careful when we write mathematics.

A possible solution would be to reserve something like $\exp(x,\alpha)$ for the function $x \mapsto x^\alpha$ with domain $(0,+\infty)$ and a generic *real* exponent $\alpha$. But nobody does this...

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean... Are you saying it is not defined?

Comment: I am saying that it is up to you. If you decide that $x^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$, then it is clearly defined. If you insist that $x^{2/3}=e^{\frac23 \log x}$, then it is undefined.